# Duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed while importing data from database using R

Tags: r, arrays, read.table

While importing data from a database(ArrayExpress) using this -

```
anno_AE <- getAE("Accessionid", path = raw_data_dir, type = "raw")
sdrf_location <- file.path(raw_data_dir, "Accessionid.sdrf.txt")
SDRF <- read.delim(sdrf_location)
```

After this-

```
rownames(SDRF) <- SDRF$Array.Data.File
```

Getting error like this-

```
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names':
```

how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You might have duplicate values in `SDRF$Array.Data.File`. Try using `make.unique` to make the values unique.

```
rownames(SDRF) <- make.unique(SDRF$Array.Data.File)
```